# Function to sort data into array by month and year is aggregating December/January. Can't work out why

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm receiving data into my program from a CSV file and I'm attempting to sort the data into a multidimensional array by year, then by month to further aggregate from there.

The trouble I'm running into is every month is aggregating and inserting into the 2D vector just fine, except for December and January. December creates its own array just fine, but then January gets added into it as well and I can't work out why.

I've been wrestling with this issue for a few days now until I finally worked out the below function for separating the data before I average it out, but I decided to check the data going into the arrays first and ran into the problem. I don't want to hard code the months if I can avoid it.

Can anyone see why it's adding January to December and not putting it into a separate vector?

Note: This is using a custom Vector class as we're not allowed to use the STL

```
void DATA::SeparateByMonth(Vector<Vector<DATA>>& byYear)
{
    long year = data[0].date.GetYear(); //initially set the year to the first found
    Vector<DATA> byMonth; //new vector to hold each month
    int j = 1; // for month counting

    for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++)
    {
        if(data[i].date.GetYear() == year)
        {
            if(data[i].date.GetMonth() == data[0].date.WhichMonth(j)) //WhichMonth has an array of months
            {
                byMonth.push_back(data[i]); // Add to Vector of Months
            }
            else
            {
                if(byMonth.length() > 0) //if vector contains data, add to ByYear
                {
                    byYear.push_back(byMonth); //Add vector to 2D vector
                }
                byMonth.clear(); //clear the vector to start again
                j++; //increment month
                i--; //decrement test by one to retest that value
            }
        }
        else
        {
            year = data[i].date.GetYear(); //change to the new year value
            j = 1; //set the check back to January
            i--; // decrement test by one to retest that value.
        }
    }
}
```

Results - length of each vector in the 2D vector

April: 4314 
May: 4464 
June: 4320 
July: 4464 
August: 4464 
September: 4320 
October: 4464 
November: 4315 
December: 8928 // December is aggregating December and January, hence no January 
February: 4032 
March: 4464

Comment: Without more code (like `data[i].date.GetMonth() == data[0].date.WhichMonth(j)` <-- those functions), it'll be hard to help you.

Comment: `j = 1; //set the check back to January` Are you sure January isn't 0?

Comment: In the month array, it sends back j-1 as the index so 1 would be month[0]

Comment: All that 0/1 stuff is ripe for opportunity to be off by one somewhere. Have you tried using a debugger? [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I have been debugging the code and using test cases, all the tests have passed so far and this is the one that fails. WhichMonth has passed all the test cases I've run through that one so far, but it seems to be failing to aggregate the data at this gate.

Comment: Are you sure those tests are correct? Tests can be wrong too. Please, if you post more code, you'll get a better response to your question. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).